# Best way to use git when a merger is anticipated

Tags: git, github, commit, git-branch

So I have a personal repo, `REPO`, which I have cloned onto multiple different systems (multiple "local" instances). Let's call these two local repos `A` and `B`. On system `A`, I know that I have uncommitted changes to the repo needing to be committed and pushed. However the system that `A` is located on is down today for maintenance. I need to do some development, so will use a different system where the local repo `B` is located.

Knowing that I am about to start development on `B`, and that unpushed changes are sitting on `A`, what is the best way to continue? Is this the appropriate scenario in which I should create a branch on `B`, and merge it to master once I have access to `A` again?

Answer (score 0):

Put your commits wherever anyone who needs them can get them, and will understand their status, and can use them as intended.  Yes, a local branch in your own B repo that won't get pushed to the main repo's master by mistake and can be merged with/rebased on the temporarily-inaccessible commits in A seems fine, there's nothing you can do to mark the A repo while it's offline.